# Vue exports.function syntax

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

i have a function like this in a separate file.

```
exports.getScore = (storeId) => {
  var getScore = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    let data = this.getScore('day', storeId)
    data.then(function (result) {
      resolve(result)
    })
  })
  let result
  await getScore.then(function (data) {
    result = data
  })
  return result
}
```

Can anyone help me with the syntax so i can make async runs, and then execute my await call? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just change the function into `this.getScore.bind(this, 'day')`

Comment: huh? how would you make the function above then? :)

Comment: i'm using this function in another components? i just want to place it one place and then refer to it instead of having it 3 places. but i don't know the syntax for making async in this way

Answer (score 0):

For your question you just need to place an `async` before your function

```
exports.getScore = async (storeId) => { /* snip */ }
```

But actually there are some problem in your code
First, you can pass a promise in Promise executor's resolve

```
new Promise(resolve => {
  // This will work
  resolve(anotherPromise)
})
```

However, if you already have a promise you can just return it directly
If you want to make sure it's a native Promise or you are not sure that it's a Promise or not.
Wrap it in `Promise.resolve`

```
Promise.resolve(anotherPromiseOrValue)
```

So your code can change into:

```
exports.getScore = (storeId) => this.getScore('day', storeId)
```

And it also equal:

```
exports.getScore = this.getScore.bind(this, 'day')
```

But there is another problem: what is the `this` here ?
If you extract this function from Vue methods, then the `this` probably is a Vue instance.
Then I afraid that the above code wont work as you expected.
So I recommend that you just use `getScore` in your component's lifecycle hook, like `mounted`

For example:

```
mounted () {
  this.getScore('day', this.storeId).then(score => {
    this.score = score
  })
}
```

Or with async/await

```
async mounted () {
  this.score = await this.getScore('day', this.storeId)
}
```

Comment: Okay, i think my problem is easy to misunderstand :)
but, my problem is. 

i have 3 files

1. login.vue
2. dashboard.vue
3. functions.js

1. i want to fill my session by running some get functions to the database here. 
2. then i want to use this sessions data on my dashboard.
3. i created my functions so i wont have 500 lines of api calls on my login page because it doesn't really make sense. 
So I have 4 functions in my functions.js where it is working because I do not need any async property on top. 
but I want to add the last 5 where i convert my promise to usable data in js

Comment: Then just add a function and await the promise